# Binary compatibility of identical struct definitions inside different classes

Tags: c++

Are identical simple struct definitions, defined in different classes, possibly different program files *compiled with same compiler and flags*, identical in memory? Common sense says they should be, but common sense and language standards don't always quite match...

Same in code, is `assertAB` method below well defined and will it always pass all asserts (assuming double value is a number)?

```
class Aclass {
public:
    struct Astruct {
        int i1;
        char s1[10];
        double d1;
    }
}

class Bclass {
private:
    struct Bstruct {
        int i2;
        const char s2[10];
        double d2;
    };

public:

    void assertAB(Aclass::Astruct s1) {
        Bstruct s2;
        std::memcpy(&s2, &s1, sizeof s2);

        assert(s1.i1 == s2.i2);
        assert(std::strncmp(s1.s1, s2.s2, sizeof (s2.s2)) == 0);
        assert(s1.d1 == s2.d2);
    }        

}
```

Comment: they are but it is a perilous path you are taking, better to use same struct for safer maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Astruct` and `Bstruct` are *layout compatible* but you are modifying a `const` object here:

```
std::memcpy(&s2, &s1, sizeof s2);
```

since `s2` in `Bstruct` is *const* and this is *undefined behavior* as we can see from the draft C++ standard section `7.1.6.1` *The cv-qualifiers* paragraph *4*:

> [...]any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.[...]

and this exact issue was actually covered in a [defect report 290](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3384.html#290) since section `3.9` *paragraph 3* seems to imply that it is valid. It says:

> 7.1.6.1 [dcl.type.cv] paragraph 4 already forbids modifying a const member of a POD struct. The prohibition need not be repeated in 3.9 [basic.types].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are. Every definition has and will have a well known size and layout. However, a 'memcpy' might defeat copy construction (if the struct is not POD)

Comment: About construction, yeah, that's why the code has `char[]` and not `std::string`.